# type conversion if flex

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am using Flerry as Java-Flex bridge for my Flex Desktop Application.

How to convert List in Java to ArrayCollection in Flex

Flex Code:-

```
[Bindable]public var screenList:ArrayCollection;
<flerry:NativeObject id="windowControllerObj" source="ls.window.EnumAllWindowNames"
  singleton="true" fault="windowControllerObj_faultHandler(event)">
    <flerry:NativeMethod id="getWindowNames" name="getAllWindowNames" 
      result="windowControllerObj_resultHandler(event)"
      fault="getWindowNames_faultHandler(event)"/>
</flerry:NativeObject>

protected function windowControllerObj_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        Alert.show("success");
        screenList.addAll(event.result as List);
        Alert.show(screenList.toString());
    }
```

Java Code:-

```
public List<String> getAllWindowNames() {
   return List<String>;
}
```

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type spark.components:List to an unrelated type mx.collections:IList.   LSFinal.mxml    /LSFinal/src    line 2289   Flex Problem

What datatypes can be converted and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to cast data type `mx.collections:IList` to UI component type `spark.components:List`, which of course leads to exception. 
Try to follow the error message hint and use `mx.collections:IList`:

```
  screenList.addAll(event.result as IList);
```

Comment: I have tried that already. It is giving the following error. `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

Comment: Which means that either `screenList` or `event.result` are null. Investigate that.